# Got an html <ul> list element filled by razor stuck on styling with css

Tags: css, razor, html-lists

i was trying to create an  list but i cant style it by id or class is there any thing i should know about razor.. Can razor block stylings and how can i give a style to this  element that will be filled with razor.

also i wanna make this list as dropdown(i dont wanna make a normal dropdown i wanna use ul element with style). its gonna show only a caption when mouse is over it, it should expand so how can i do it?

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Admin", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td></td><td></td>
                <td colspan="2">
                    <div class="editor-label">Product</div>
                    <div id="d1" class="editor-field">
                        <input id="iProduct" type="text" />
                        <input id="ProductSub" type="button" style="padding:5px; margin-top:15px;" value="Add New Product" onclick="productsub()"/>
                        @foreach (var Product in (new SelectList((System.Collections.IEnumerable)ViewData["Productlist"], "id", "name")))
                        {
                            <ul id="nanik">
                                <li id="@Product.Value">@Product.Text</li>
                            </ul>
                        }
                    </div>
                </td>
```

Also if u can tell me if u know how to turn it into dropdown that would be awesome..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest that you open the web page with Google Chrome or Firefox with Firebug installed and use their Inspect element to see why the CSS is not used for styling the list. I'm guessing that some other CSS code has overridden your list styling.

Comment: i seperated all element's css attributes. It doesnt seem posible cause thanks to .net mvc i can see all changes i made in it. So i double checked the main css files no overriding in css. While i checked it i also see that some basic stylings working like text-align but other coloring or border is not working at all.

Comment: Can you post your page on a public web server? Static HTML file of your dynamic page with the same CSS files is fine too.

Comment: because of the security issues i cannot. i would but my employer would have a "little" conversation with me.

but i can give a link of my css file + some more info of my code in my view.

Comment: Can you provide a stripped down version of the page as HTML copy? Preferrably the kind with only the problematic list. Solving the problem just by looking at CSS code is probably hard.

Comment: i found the problem ur right there is an overriding. so ty for that. i found a link goes for a file in style as behaviour. so when i checked it found that i was using it for IE rounded corners that was the thing doing all those complications so its solved.